# PHP thumb resize png image but add black background

Tags: php, phpthumb

I am using   [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) to resize images rumtime. It is working fine but it add black background on PNG image. 
How could I resolve this?
my path is

```
phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src={imagepath}&w=95&h=92
```

Comment: `phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src={imagepath}&w=95&h=92&f=png`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is  the example to avoid black background:

```
src="/uploads/phpThumb.php?src=images/expressionengine_logo.png&w=100&f=png" 

src="/uploads/phpThumb.php?src=images/expressionengine_logo.png&w=100&bg=D4E9F7"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing [ImageCreateFromJPEG](http://www.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg)($file) with [ImageCreateFromPNG](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)($file)

Most probably this is the common error for the black background in the resized pngimage

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am not familiar with `PHPThumb` but you can use **[SimpleImage](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/)** library with **[this](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/retaining-transparency-with-php-image-resizing/)** update.

I am using it and didnt faced any problems yet. This library has purposefully updated for the problem you are facing right now. Go to the links and try to use it.